# TCP client can not receive response from server

Tags: azure, web, tcp, server, virtual-machine

I use Microsoft Azure Visual Machine to build TCP transmission.
It works normally that client send message to server,
but server could not send response to client.

The error message show as below:

```
[NettyOrderedWorker] [ERROR] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-k823vmzjw01-39487-1545119096585-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-k823vmzjw01-39487-1545119096585-0-2).Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: RequestModel{dataLength=22, dataType=1, yy=18, mm=3, dd=27, hh=20, mh=48, ss=35, suii=-32768, suion=1000, comment1=0, comment2=0}]
```

However, when I used the same code to work in my localhost, it works normally.

Please tell me how to solve the problem on Azure VM.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You're probably connecting to a specific port number. Is that port opened on the VM?

Comment: yes, the server port set 9999 and the client port set random.

Comment: When I used UDP transmission , this problem did not happen.